# Writing MATLAB with the original font in modernCV

Tags: fonts, moderncv, cv

I'm wondering if I can write MATLAB with the original font in my CV using class `moderncv`:

[image: Matlab logo]

Thank you for your willingness.

Comment: Do you have a license of the commercial typeface required to typeset this logo?

Comment: what you try so far? if you know and have original font, than `\textsc{Matlab}\textsuperscript{\circledR}` can help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you have a look to [the german page of MATLAB about Trademarks](https://de.mathworks.com/company/aboutus/policies_statements/trademarks.html?s_tid=gf_trd)  you will find:

[image]

As you can see it the registered mark set with only uppercase letters. About the font was nothing said, but it is a font without serif!

Because an cv is usualy set in non serif font (class option `sans`) you can use the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % <=========================

\moderncvtheme{classic}

\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp} % <===============================================

\name{Joe}{Doe} 


\begin{document}

MATLAB\textsuperscript{\textregistered} % <=============================
MATLAB\textsuperscript{\texttrademark}
\end{document}
```

In this way you respect the layout on the homepage but use your font in the cv. 
On the homepage of MATLAB the name of the software is printed without registered mark, but uppercase. So it seems okay to use only MATLAB in your cv.

The printed logos with class `moderncv` are then:

[image: printed logo]

That is near enouph to the original logo so one would recognize the used software as MATLAB. If you realy want to use the completely original logo you need to contact the owner of the logo, and ask for the specifications for the logo:

1. font,
2. fontsize,
3. color,
4. needed space around the logo
5. other specifications they have to allow using there logo to be used.

That could get problematic if you want to add more than one logo to your cv in its original form.

Please note that it is not very good to use a lot of different fonts perhaps in different font sizes in one document ...

Please note that there can be -- depending on the place you live -- a legal problem using logos in the original font: Often logos are set in commercial fonts, you need to own to be allowed to use them in your cv. That can be get very explensive soon ... Or you simply are not allowed to use the original logo ...

At last: to be sure ask a layer what is allowed in the place you live ...

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi well, in your image the font uses serifes, but that is not the way the logo is shown on the official web page of MATLAB. Where do you have this logo/image? Do they have informations about the used color and font? Could it be you show us an outdated one? Are you allowed to use that logo?

Comment: if I want to use the logo in the normal text, have I to ask the permission to Matlab company?